# Can't create a custom token in firebase cloud functions because the service account doesn't have the necessary permissions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions, google-iam

When calling `admin.auth().createCustomToken()`, I get the following error:

> Permission iam.serviceAccounts.signBlob is required to perform this operation on service account projects/-/serviceAccounts/kaleido-maastricht@appspot.gserviceaccount.com.; Please refer to https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens for more details on how to use and troubleshoot this feature.

So I go look at the mentioned service account in the IAM section of the cloud platform console, and it has the `Editor` role, which, indeed, does not have the `signBlob` permission. What role could I change it to to fix this? I tried creating a custom role based on Editor, but the createBlob permission can't be added to custom roles.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The page of documentation you linked to has a section for troubleshooting at the bottom.  You're directed to [read there](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens#service_account_does_not_have_required_permissions) for help.  It says:

> If the service account ID used to sign tokens does not have the
>   iam.serviceAccounts.signBlob permission, you may get an error message
>   like the following:
>
> ```
> Permission iam.serviceAccounts.signBlob is required to perform this
> operation on service account
> projects/-/serviceAccounts/{your-service-account-id}.
> ```
>
> The easiest way to resolve this is to grant the "Service Account Token
>   Creator" IAM role to the service account in question:
>
> 1. Open the IAM and admin page in the Google Cloud Platform Console.
> 2. Select your project and click "Continue".
> 3. Click the edit icon corresponding to the service account ID you wish to update.
> 4. Click on "Add Another Role".
> 5. Type "Service Account Token Creator" into the search filter, and select it from the results.
> 6. Click "Save" to confirm the role grant.
>
> Refer to IAM documentation for more details on this process, or learn
>   how to do update roles using the gcloud command-line tools.

Comment: Thx! I visited that page, but somehow missed that section.

Comment: I get the same error message, but it is not resolved by granting the "Service Account Token Creator" to the specified service account. Any ideas on why I would still get this error message after granting that role to the service account?

Comment: Make sure you're modifying the correct service account.

Comment: I'm certain it's the correct service account -- I've copied and pasted from the cli output to identify it in IAM console and confirm it has the "Service Account Token Creator" role.

Comment: Which service account did you modify?

Comment: I get the error message `Permission iam.serviceAccounts.signBlob is required to perform this operation on service account projects/-/serviceAccounts/firebase-adminsdk-u29pb@hugh-test-env.iam.gserviceaccount.com.;`. I've granted the "Service Account Token Creator" role to the service account `firebase-adminsdk-u29pb@hugh-test-env.iam.gserviceaccount.com`.

Comment: Is that the account you're initializing the Admin SDK with?  If you're not choosing a service account at init time, then that's the wrong one.  You want the "App Engine default service account", which is what's taken by default when you init with no arguments.

Comment: Thanks, I've added what seemed to get it working for me as another answer.

Comment: The instructions above are out of date, the UI has changed quite a bit. after step 2 above: 3) select the service account with  "@appspot" in the "Email" column 4) In the sidebar pick "Add Member" 5) type "appspot" in the "New Members" field 6) click on the service account in the dropdown 7) click on "select a role" 8) click on "type to filter" 9) type or paste in "Service Account Token Creator" 10) click on the role in the drop down 11) click on "save"

Comment: @DougStevenson but why does the error mention a specific service account if that's not the right one?  Just a bug on their end, maybe?  I'm even explicitly initializing my app with a certain service account, but giving it the role didn't work while giving my app's default service account the role did work.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same error, and could see that the service account had the "Service Account Token Creator" role in the GCP IAM console UI.

What solved it for me:

Make sure you're using the right Firebase project:

```
firebase use your-project
```

Make sure you're using the "App Engine default service account", e.g. `your-project@appspot.gserviceaccount.com`.

Grant the role to that service account via the gcloud cli:

```
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding your-project --member serviceAccount:your-project@appspot.gserviceaccount.com --role roles/iam.serviceAccountTokenCreator
```

Deploy Firebase:

```
firebase deploy
```

After that it did work for me (but not after setting it via the UI without a deployment).

I think this ought to display the role on the service account:

```
gcloud iam service-accounts get-iam-policy your-project@appspot.gserviceaccount.com --project your-project
```

But for me still gives `etag: ACAB`, even though I can see the role on the output of the previous command, and can see that the role works as it's now able to create custom tokens.

Comment: Giving the @appspot.gserviceaccount.com account the permission is what did it for me. I was specifying a different service account in my init which I had given access, but I could never get it to work.

Comment: Thank you for this! I also added the role in the GCP IAM web app and could not figure out why I was still getting the error.

Comment: Adding Service Account Toke Creator role for "App Engine default service account" solves my problem too.

Answer (score 6):

Go to console accessing this link [https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/iam?project=[project-id]](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/iam) following these steps:

1. Click the edit icon **[your-project]@appspot.gserviceaccount.com**
2. Click on **Add Another Role**
3. Type **Service Account Token Creator** into the search filter, and select it from the results
4. Click **Save** to confirm

Comment: Just and addition to your answer. I added the role in GCP but I was still getting the error until I redeployed the cloud function.
Hope it helps someone. Cheers!